# run rscript on local in a docker image

Tags: r, windows, docker, containers, kaggle

I have pulled a kaggle/rstats image on my local windows machine. I want to run a local code script.r in the kaggle image.

My code script.r is stored in "D:/codes/script.r." I have installed docker and pulled kaggle/rstats image in "E:/docker."

Can somebody please help with how to run script.r in kaggle docker image.

I have been using the following command to run it but of course there is some issue with it which I can't figure out.

```
docker run -v $PWD:D:/codes -w=D:/codes --rm -it kaggle/rstats Rscript script.r
```

Output:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid bind mount spec "/c/Users/Rohan:D:/codes": invalid mode: /codes.
>   See 'E:\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

I tried following as well:

```
docker run -v /D:/codes -w=/D:/codes --rm -it kaggle/rstats Rscript script.r
```

Output:

> Fatal error: cannot open file 'script.r': No such file or directory

script.r is present in D:/codes, not sure why it is saying `no such file`.

What is wrong in the command?

Comment: Can you add the output of your command?

Comment: @buddy123 added. I tried one more thing. Added that as well with its output.

Comment: You get the first error because the `:` is interpreted as permissions for folder by docker client. Can you try the second option with full path? i.e `Rscript /codes/script.r`?

Comment: @buddy123 i tried. Still the same error (no such file or directory). Can this be happening because image is installed in E: drive, when I start docker quickstart terminal it is in C drive by default.